# How to proper use HTML5 tags Article and Section?

Tags: html, css, tags

I have this kind of structure, but i am not shure how to proper use HTML5 tags on this mockup,  like article, section etc.

Can someone can tell me how to proper wrap elements?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like an outline

```
<section class="Tab1">
    <section class="TabA">
    </section>
    <section class="TabB">
    </section>
</section>
<section class="Tab2">
</section>
<section class="Tab3">
</section>
<section class="Tab4">
</section>
```

No need for article unless there is something from an author other than yourself.

> article: An article is like a section, but it's intended for use with
>   external resources. Many pages are built automatically by software,
>   and when these pages integrate content from other sources, it's
>   intended to use the article tag to integrate this content.

[Source](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-semantic-tags-for-html5-and-css3-progra.html)